# Table valued parameter "sniffing"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameter-sniffing

I have a stored procedure (SP) in which a table-valued parameter (TVP) is being passed in. The same code in the SP executes a lot slowly than it does outside the SP.

I took a look at the execution plans and they are very different.

At first this seemed like a sign of parameter sniffing, however this is for a TVP! Which works a bit differently (I am not too certain - apparently there is no sniffing for TVP's?).

In any case, if I create a new local TVP and insert the rows into it, then I get a good execution plan!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TVPSniffTest] (
    @GuidList dbo.Guid_LIST readonly
)
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @GuidList2 dbo.Guid_LIST
    INSERT INTO @GuidList2 
    SELECT * FROM @GuidList

   --query code here using @GuidList2, produces a good plan!
END
```

What is going on?

Edit I've tried a number of query optimizer hints, they do not work. Including the one in the suggested duplicate question. It's almost like the bad plan (slow one), is the one that is correct in terms of the estimated number of rows. The fast plan has an incorrect estimation of the number of rows.

Comment: TVPs don't have statistics, so the estimated number of rows is always 1.

Comment: Thanks. Recompile query hint does not help.

Comment: Post the plans and the code.

Answer (score 2):

TVPs don't have *distribution statistics*, but they do have **cardinality** information.

**Parameter sniffing** applies to table-valued parameters: the optimizer might reuse a plan compiled for a low-cardinality TVP in a following invocation of the SP on a TVP with many rows.

Sources:

- Erland Sommarskog's **Arrays and Lists in SQL Server: The Long Version**
  ([section *13.1 Performance in SQL Server*](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#Server-side))
- BrentOzar's [Table Valued Parameters: Unexpected Parameter Sniffing](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/03/table-valued-parameters-unexpected-parameter-sniffing/) (see *"Second Thing: They don’t get a fixed estimate like Table Variables"* and *"Third Thing: Non-join cardinality estimates behave like local variables (fixed estimates)"*)